# Use a switch statement to return different page instances

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, switch-statement

I'm slightly new to Java and am using it with selenium. I've got a common page object class that has different methods performing the same task but returning different pages depending on how you got there (i.e. which method you call). So what I want to do is create one method with a switch statement that will return different page instances.

As the header text on the page will reflect the journey to the shared page, I was thinking I could use the `INVOICE_HEADER_IDENTIFIER` as the switch value perhaps? Just looking for some guidance and best practice in this case.

```java
public AccomodationInvoiceDetails searchForStudentAccomodationInvoice(String studentNo){
    assertThat(getTextFromElement(INVOICE_HEADER_IDENTIFIER).equals("Create Accommodation Invoice : Select Invoice")).isTrue();
    enterTextIntoElement(SELECT_STUDENT_FIELD_IDENTIFIER, "1990514");
    clickElement(NEXT_BUTTON_IDENTIFIER);
    waitForElementToBeDisplayed(By.id("ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.1."), driver, 10);
    return new AccomodationInvoiceDetails(driver);
}

public CreditNoteSelectInvoicePage searchForStudentAccomodationCreditNote(String studentNo){
    assertThat(getTextFromElement(INVOICE_HEADER_IDENTIFIER).equals("Create Accommodation Credit Note : Select Student")).isTrue();
    enterTextIntoElement(SELECT_STUDENT_FIELD_IDENTIFIER, "1990514");
    clickElement(NEXT_BUTTON_IDENTIFIER);
    waitForElementToBeDisplayed(By.id("ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.1."), driver, 10);
    return new CreditNoteSelectInvoicePage(driver);
}
```

Comment: have a try at my solution

Comment: Have you gone through the given solution

Comment: Hi @PritamMaske Ive not had chance as yet. I'll aim to do this today and get back to you.

Comment: @PritamMaske That worked perfectly thankyou. I just had to case to the page in my Test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try this :**

```
public Object searchForStudentAccomodation(String studentNo){
        String invoiceHeader = getTextFromElement(INVOICE_HEADER_IDENTIFIER);
        switch (invoiceHeader){
            case "Create Accommodation Credit Note : Select Student" :
                commonInvoiceAction(studentNo);
                return new CreditNoteSelectInvoicePage(driver); 

            case "Create Accommodation Invoice : Select Invoice" :
                commonInvoiceAction(studentNo);
                return new AccomodationInvoiceDetails(driver);

            default :
                System.out.println("Invalid invoice header : "+invoiceHeader);
                return  null;

        }
    }

    public void commonInvoiceAction(String studentNo){
        enterTextIntoElement(SELECT_STUDENT_FIELD_IDENTIFIER, studentNo);
        clickElement(NEXT_BUTTON_IDENTIFIER);
        waitForElementToBeDisplayed(By.id("ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.1."), driver, 10);
    }
```